# Parse response body from request and return back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, pipe

I am new to node.js and JavaScript in general, but I'm trying to use node.js as a simple REST API. A client request comes to node.js, then node.js reaches out to a database to perform crud operations and returns the response back. However, I would like to be able to parse this response and format it in my own JSON before sending back to the client. Right now im using the request library and `.pipe()` to send back. Can I `.pipe()` into a variable that I could then parse or do I need to change my approach entirely?

Here is what my code looks like at the current moment:

```
const request = require('request');

var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
    request({
        uri: 'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/search?q=caesar',
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": auth
        }   
    }).pipe(res);

};
```

I am aware that `request` has been deprecated so maybe there is a better way to do this currently. I appreciate any help and feedback as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request` module or `axios` or anything. You can just save the JSON body and process it and sent it to the client. Below is how to do it.

```
const request = require('request');

var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  request({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/search?q=caesar',
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": auth
    }
   // You can set json:true here so that you don't have to do JSON.parse below.
  }, (err, response, body)=>{
    //body is the json body
    const jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
    //do something with json request
    res.json(jsonBody);
  })
};
```